# What is causing the vertical misalignment inside the list item on Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

[This markup](https://jsbin.com/lecozebawe/1/edit?html,css,output) is a stripped-down version of the real markup in a complex application. I can't easily change it. I have abstracted it and reduced it to the bare minimum required to troubleshoot the issue.

If you view this bin in Chrome and Firefox the difference will be obvious. If you toggle the commented `display: block` in the `a > span` rule you'll see that it is responsible for the misalignment. I can't really figure out why, or how to fix it on the affected browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This did get rid of the misalignment / vertical space, but also the list item bullet… Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: I updated my code. Try this display:flex for a. and remove my old code display:block from li.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain *why* this works and what the cause of the issue is?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to make below changes in **a > span** class may help to fix this issue for Firefox and IE browser.

```
a > span {
/*  display: block is needed for truncation  */
display:inline-block;
width:250px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
div {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #4d4e4c;
/* word-break is inhertied */
 word-break: break-all;
  width: 300px;
  outline: 1px dashed #ccc;

}

ul {

}

li {
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

a {
 
}

a > span {
/*  display: block is needed for truncation  */
display:inline-block;
width:250px;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>
            <span>Item 1</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>
            <span>Item 2</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
          <span>
            <span>Item 3 is long and requires truncation</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in various browsers:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `a > span` can't be of a fixed width.

Comment: You should inform all your requirements in your original post. If you remove the width then you will not get ellipsis effect. Solution will still work.